# KeyError: "None of ['minute'] are in the columns" when setting index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib

import datetime
import fxcmpy
import numpy as np

print(con.get_instruments())
symbols = con.get_instruments()

ticker = 'NGAS'
start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
data1= con.get_candles(ticker, period='m1', number=10000)

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm %s')
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm %s')
data['hour'] = data.index.hour
data['minute'] = data.index.minute
```

All fine till here:

When i run

```
data.set_index('minute', inplace = True)
data.set_index('hour', inplace = True)
```

I get the following error

```
KeyError: "None of ['minute'] are in the columns"
```

How can i set both hour and minute as index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using *fxcmpy* I read *data* from a source CSV file,
such that it contained initially:

```
                        C1     C2
2019-05-02 12:33 22  Xxxx1  Yyyy1
2019-05-04 10:12 00  Xxxx2  Yyyy2
2019-05-05 16:54 13  Xxxx3  Yyyy3
```

(the index with no name, as **string**).

Your error is in *format* parameter:

- The **hour** format should be *%H* (one capital *H*, not *%hh*).
- The **minute** format should be *%M (one capital *M*, not *%mm*).
- The **second** format should be *%S* (also upper case).

For details see https://strftime.org/

So correct your code to:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S')
```

and your DataFrame will have the index changed to *datetime64*.

Then

```
data['hour'] = data.index.hour
data['minute'] = data.index.minute
```

should execute without error (at least I got no error).

But the way you wrote 2 **separate** instructions, setting index first to *hour*
and **then** to *minute* looks strange.

Maybe you want to create a MultiIndex with **both** *hour* and *minute* columns?
If this is the case, run:

```
data.set_index(['hour', 'minute'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! My other projects had problems too and %H:%M %S was the issue.